# Rails update_attributes RecordNotUnique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to overwrite a record in rails 4.0.

```
old_p.update_attributes(new_p.attributes)
```

`old_p` is the record pulled from the database, `new_p` is the record the user has created that will replace the record from the database. `new_p` actually has its own record in the database, but is only stored there temporarily.

This seems to work some of the times, but most of the time it comes back with

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in Controller#overwrite
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

This is an upgrade from rails 2, and seemed to have been working as expected when it was a rails 2 app. There seems to be little documentation on update_attributes, but it seems as if it is copying the id of the object as well.

I have also tried assign_attributes with .save later, but to the same effect.

If it is copying the id of the object as well, is there a way to easily leave out the id? As the record has some 20+ attributes I would have to manually enter and they could change often. Or is there something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
old_p.update_attributes(new_p.attributes.tap { |h| h.delete('id')})
```

Comment: I believe this should work, but I ended up using the except method: http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except